# How to join two datasets "lat/lon log data" and "hexagonal cells grid data" SQL or python

Tags: python, sql, postgis

I have two datasets as below.

data 1：lat/lon log

```
#log_id, lat, lon
0001 , 31.30272 , 103.66426
0002 , 31.23483 , 103.12323
：
```

data 2：hexagonal cells grid infomation

```
#grid_id, point1_lat , point1_lon , ・・・　, point6_lat , point6_lon
000001, 31.30272 , 103.66426 , 31.30272 , 103.66426 ,　・・・　, 31.30242 , 103.65676
：
```

How can　I extract the grid ID in data 2 corresponding to the log ID in data 1 as below.

```
log_id , grid_id
0001 , 000324
0002 , 002341
：
```

I'm using PostgreSQL or python

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to use the outer merger to merge two or more datasets in one

example:

```
merged_data = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='outer)
```

then you can select the two id's from merged data

```
selected_columns = merged_data[merged_data['log_id'] & merged_data['grid_id']]
print(selected_columns)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.
Since Data 2 is a hexagonal cell grid, I wonder that it is necessary to judge whether the position data (lattitude/longitude) of Data 1 is within the area of ​​the hexagonal cell grid of Data 2.